# Extract part of a list given start value in excel

Tags: excel

I want to extract part of a list given the starting value found by means of index/match combinations or the vlookup function. However, hence only the initial value is returned but subsequent values in the list are also of interest and should follow this initial found value. Is there a way of combining functions that return sub-arrays? Thank you in advance for the help. Best Regards, Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we wanted the **UK** people, *VLOOKUP()* would only return *William.*  If we want more than just *William*, then in **C1** enter:

**UK**

and in **C2** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$22, SMALL(IF(C$1=$A$2:$A$22, ROW($A$2:$A$22)-MIN(ROW($A$2:$A$22))+1, ""), ROW(A1))),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Incrementing Row/Column Count Options

#### 1a. Start Value, Sub-List Length

Let us assume this sample data and result format:

```
 A          B                 C      D
---------------------------------------------
1|John      Start Value       Amy    Amy
2|Jane      Sub-List Length   3      Amber
3|Amy                                Chris
4|Amber                 
5|Chris                 
6|Dan                   
7|Bob
```

You can achieve this by using the following formula and autofilling down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,(MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,0))+IF(ROWS($1:1)<=$C$2,ROWS($1:1)-1,#VALUE!)),"")
```

---

#### 1b. Start Value, End Value

Sample data and result format:

```
 A          B             C      D
---------------------------------------------
1|John      Start Value   Amy    Amy
2|Jane      End Value     Dan    Amber
3|Amy                            Chris
4|Amber                          Dan
5|Chris                 
6|Dan                   
7|Bob
```

Use this formula and autofill down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,(MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,0))+IF(ROWS($1:1)<=(MATCH($C$2,$A:$A,0)-MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,0)+1),ROWS($1:1)-1,#VALUE!)),"")
```

#### 1c. Start Value, End of list

---

Sample data and result format:

```
 A          B             C      D
---------------------------------------------
1|John      Start Value   Chris  Chris
2|Jane                           Dan
3|Amy                            Bob
4|Amber                              
5|Chris                 
6|Dan                   
7|Bob
```

Use this formula and autofill down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,(MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,0))+IF(ROWS($1:1)<=(COUNTA($A:$A)-MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,0)+1),ROWS($1:1)-1,#VALUE!)),"")
```

---

**Note:** for options 1a - 1c if you wish to have a horizontal list result replace `ROWS($1:1)` with `COLUMNS($A:A)` and autofill *to the right*

---

### 2. Using a Predefined Array:

**Note:** These options requires you to select the range you want the values to be in, and then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to enter the data.

---

#### 2a. Vertical Sublist, Fixed Length:

Sample data and result format, with fixed length of 4

```
 A          B             C      D
---------------------------------------------
1|John      Start Value   Amy    Amy 
2|Jane                           Amber
3|Amy                            Chris
4|Amber                          Dan 
5|Chris                 
6|Dan                   
7|Bob
```

Select cells `D1:D4` and enter in this formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,0)+TRANSPOSE({0,1,2,3}))
```

Then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

#### 2b. Horizontal Sublist, Fixed Length:

Sample data and result format, with fixed length of 4

```
 A          B             C      D      E       F      G
----------------------------------------------------------
1|John      Start Value   Amy    Amy    Amber   Chris  Dan
2|Jane                           
3|Amy                            
4|Amber                           
5|Chris                 
6|Dan                   
7|Bob
```

Same as last formula without `TRANSPOSE` and selecting cells `D1:G1`:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH($C$1,$A:$A,0)+{0,1,2,3})
```

Again, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

**Note:** To increment the length add additional values to the array `{0,1,2,3, ...}`